# ILMerging dll's and EXE together. New EXE fail to work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, executable, ilmerge

I'm using Command Prompt to use IlMerge, which worked, no doubt, I got the new .EXE as output.

I've merged with following files:

> - application.exe (Winform app C#)
> - System.IO.Compression.dll (Required in the application.exe)
> - System.IO.Compression.Filesystem.dll (Required in the application.exe)

I've used following command to create the "merging":

```
ILMerge /out:GameLauncher.exe application.exe System.IO.Compression.dll System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
```

But the problem I did get, was whenever I tried to execute/run this new .exe(GameLauncher.exe), it immediately said the default "APPLICATION_NAME stopped working...", and then closed after a few seconds of that message.

I can't figure out what's wrong, my guess would be that it can't figure out, which methods from the "application.exe" to run in the new .exe. But again, that's just my first assumption, which I've still tried to research, and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Check the event log to see what exception was being thrown. It will help you to spot the problem

Comment: Don't ILMerge .NET Framework assemblies.

Comment: @HansPassant If you had to come with that comment, atleast explain why I shouldn't, or what else I should do. A simple "Don't do that" doesn't help me alot, and quite frankly. Helping, is what Stackoverflow is all about.

Comment: Also, the reason why I need to merge those DLL's, is that their aren't available on older computers, which is why I need this "extra safety" to ensure most outdated windows machines, can run it.